# Decidable questions of undecidable problems

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability

Even if there is no general algorithm to decide if any program will halt, but there could be properties or meta-questions about the programs that is decidable. For example, given program $A$ and a program $B$ that is obtainable from program $A$ by adding in finite steps of calculations that halts.
So if $A$ halts, $B$ definitely halts (and vice versa). A trivial example is $B = A$.

The question "Do $A$ and $B$ have the **same** behaviour?" is decidable (they either both halt or run forever), even if we do not know whether $A$ or $B$ halts or not.

My question: Is it true that, for any program $A$, there is always a non-trivial program $B$ such that there is a decidable meta-question about the duo $(A, B)$?
(Non-trivial means $B ≠ A$ and $B$ is not obtainable from $A$ via adding extra finite steps that halts. In general, it means $B\neq f(A)$, where $f$ is a computable function.)

I wonder if there is a field of research on this type of meta-problems?

Comment: "Do A and B have the same behavior" is very much not decidable. If it were I could just set A to a known halting machine and then ask whether arbitrary program B halts by asking A = B?

Comment: @orlp I have edited the question to mention that the finite extra steps halts.

Comment: Your non-triviality requirement doesn't make sense: for any *specific* $A$ and $B$ (with any relationship at all) there is a computable function on Turing machine indices sending $A$ to $B$ - namely, just send *everything* to $B$. Precisely defining nontriviality in this context is going to be - appropriately enough - nontrivial.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, the non-triviality is suppose to mean one can’t find out about the computability of $B$, given the computability of $A$.  I think sending $A$ to $B$ does not achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced by your setup. All programs are finite sequences of steps, so the equivalence of $A$ and $B$ in your first paragraph isn't decidable: they're equivalent iff $B$ halts on every input that $A$ halts on.

Your main question seems to be under-specified in a way that makes it trivial. The empty langauge is a decidable problem about pairs $(A,B)$. For any computable function $f$, the language $\{(A,B)\mid B=f(A)\}$ is decidable. But I suspect that any attempt to make the problem more precise will fail because of the issue I raised above.

Comment: Thanks. I think you have stated what I was trying to capture. Can I amend the question to: by non-trivial it means B is not a computable function of A.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation:

There is no decidable language $L = \{(A,B)|B = f(A)\}$, where $f$ is non-computable and not semi-computable.

Proof:
If $L$ was decidable there would be a Turing-Machine $T$ that decides it.
We select $T$ in such a way that it has a single reject and a single accept state.
This is possible since our language is decidable.
Now we look at a specific Input $A$. We construct the Turing-Maschine $T_A$ that prints $A$ out and then runs $T$. $T_A$ basically "expects another input B".
We know want to find an input to $T_A$ such that $T_A$ accepts. We can do that buy. Iterating through all strings $B$ and run $T_A$ on $B$. Since $T_A$ always halts we will either find a $B$ that results in an accept state or the procedure will run forever.
Thus $f$ is semi-computable. This is a contradiction ans hence the statement is true.

Feedback? Is the proof correct?